# MySQL: standard approach VS set-based approach for multi-row results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recursive-query, set-based

Following up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335766/mysql-multi-rows-result-vs-single-row-result), there is problem with **the standard approach** or **a recursive approach** in the case below.

For instance, I want to return the page with the same `parent_id` and some pages have **multiple row contents**,

`page` table

```
page_id    page_title   parent_id
1          a            1
2          aa           1
3          ab           1
4          ac           1
```

`content` table

```
content_id   content_text
1            text one
2            text two
3            text one aa
4            text two aa
5            text one ab
6            text one ac
```

`content structure` table

```
page_id     content_id     order_in_page
1           1              1
1           2              2
2           3              1
2           4              2
3           5              1
4           6              1
```

The standard approach,

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    c.*,
    x.*

FROM pages AS p

LEFT JOIN pages_structures AS x
ON x.page_id = p.page_id

LEFT JOIN  pages_contents AS c
ON c.content_id = x.content_id

WHERE p.parent_id = '1'
AND p.page_id  != '1'
```

result (it lists the row as 4 items),

```
page_id   page_title  parent_id   content_text    order_in_page
2         aa           1          text one aa        1    
2         aa           1          text two aa        2
3         ab           1          text one ab        1
4         ac           1          text one ac        1
```

As you can notice that there are **two rows** with `page_id 2` and **one row** for each `3` and `4`. How do you display the data into HTML with **the standard approach** like below (as suggested in one of the answer in the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335766/mysql-multi-rows-result-vs-single-row-result))?

```
echo $page[0]['page_title'];
echo $page[0]['content_text'];
```

But with **set-based** one, I can do it with this,

```
SELECT
   page_id,
   page_title, 
   MAX(IF(order_in_page = 1, content_text, NULL)) AS content_1,
   MAX(IF(order_in_page = 2, content_text, NULL)) AS content_2,
   .
   .
   .
FROM 
   pages AS p LEFT JOIN 
   pages_structures AS x ON x.page_id = p.page_id LEFT JOIN  
   pages_contents AS c ON c.content_id = x.content_id
WHERE
   p.parent_id = '1'
AND
   p.page_id != '1'
GROUP BY page_id
```

in PHP,

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
    echo '<li><h3>'.$item['page_title'].'</h3>';
    echo '<p>'.$item['content_1'].'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$item['content_2'].'</p></li>';
}
```

the HTML (it lists the row as 3 items which is correct),

```
<li>
   <h3>aa</h3>
   <p>text one aa</p>
   <p>text two aa</p>
</li>

<li>
   <h3>ab</h3>
   <p>text one ab</p>
   <p></p>
</li>

<li>
   <h3>ac</h3>
   <p>text one ac</p>
   <p></p>
</li>
```

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

with the standard approach you just keep track of the current page in a variable, and when the page changes, you roll to a new list item.